# Execute process in debug mode from current dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, process

I have a Windows forms application which is internally calling an exe file. Now I am trying to execute this exe file in debugging mode but unable to do so. Is there any way I can debug my exe file while this current application runs?

```
  Dim proc As Process = New Process()
  proc.StartInfo.FileName = "DllReader.exe"
  proc.StartInfo.Arguments = path & " " & dllFileName
  proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
  proc.Start()
  proc.WaitForExit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Open your Windows Forms app in Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to the point in the app where the second app is launched and launch it.
3. Open the solution for the second app in another instance of Visual Studio.
4. Hit CTRL-ALT-P (Attach to Process) and select the process that is running the second executable.

You can now step through code.

Comment: That what the first thing I tried. but I dont see Attach to Process in Debug menu (also CTRL-ALT-P is not working) ..may be because the application is in vb.net (Framework 3.5) and process is in c#.net (Framework 4.0) ?

Comment: Attach To Process is in the "Tools" menu.